# Maven Issue while Running SpringBoot Project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, validation, dependencies, pom.xml

Plugin validation issues were detected in 1 plugin(s)

- org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0

For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]

How can i Fix this ?

Comment: This is a WARNING (it's hint to plugin authors).... See https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.2/release-notes.html First step is to upgrade your exec-maven-plugin to most recent version  (https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and the question comes into my mind why do you need exec-maven-plugin for a spring boot project?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the [WARNING](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.2/release-notes.html) by using the most recent version of the [exec-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

The warning has the reason that the plugin authors using Maven 2 compatible API which will not be supported anymore for Maven 4 or using other out-of-date parts.

Some more details can be found [here](https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/06/2023-06-warnings-maven-3.9/).